# Spring's AuthenticationProcessingFilter override

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to override AuthenticationProcessingFilter in Spring security. I have done following config in xml:

```
<security:http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" >
        <security:intercept-url .../>
        <security:form-login login-page='/signin/' authentication-failure-url="/signin/?login_error" default-target-url='/signin/success'/>
        <security:anonymous/>
        <security:logout/>
        <security:remember-me/>
</security:http>

<bean class="myPackage.security.SessionCleanerFilter" >
    <security:custom-filter position="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/signin/success" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/signin/?login_error" />
    <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
</bean>
```

But this fails with lots of exceptions

> Error creating bean with name
>   'myPackage.security.SessionCleanerFilter#0'

due to lack of instatiation properties. I would like them to be default. Do you know how to configure them?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
<security:custom-filter position=“AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER”/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to disable auto-config:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
```

and then, you no longer need the `<security:form-login>` tag, since you are setting the same properties in your bean.

Comment: `auto-config` is false by default, so that shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you need to follow purely depends upon what you really want to do inside your Custom Filter.

I hit upon similar problem, have a look at this post for few suggestions https://stackoverflow.com/a/12356510/686478 .

`security:form-login` internally creates a bean definition for AuthenticationProcessingFilter, and hence re-defining it at same position (in your case its FORM_LOGIN_FILTER or AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER as it was called in [2.x](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters) ) would cause error because the bean is already defined by http namespace handler. See [Adding Your own filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters) section of ref manual.

Easy option is to set auto-config to false, remove `<form-login>` and define your auth filter in predefined position, but by doing this you will also loose usability and readability of your security config, and you will have to manage [the dependencies of your AuthenticationProcessingFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html) on your own (like setting AuthenticationManager,filterProcessesUrl etc. ).

If you really do not want to overwrite existing auth filter but actually just want to do some pre/post processing, Another alternative is to define your custom filter using after or before attributes,which gets invoked before or after the actual filter.

**Note:** Based on your subject line, I presume you are intended to use  AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER  and not FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR which is alias for  FilterSecurityInterceptor.

<sub>I know this is kind of outdated post, but I Hope this will help a few :)</sub>